# How to create a log of the processing of tabular models

Tags: tabular, ssas-tabular

Can anyone tell me how to create a log table that collects all actions happening when processing a tabular database? I would like to collect the data in a similar fashion as the SQL Server Profiler trace can do.

I would also like collected data to be stored in a table that I can query later on. We process the models using SQL Server Agent, and the table should be updated automatically whenever this is used to process a tabular model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great post about using Extended Events to capture what's going on in SSAS, http://markvsql.com/2014/02/introduction-to-analysis-services-extended-events/.